# TestCafe: How to test logout if user logged in from another machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a scenario where I want to start running a test on chrome and at specific point I want my test to open different browser (firefox) and to do the same steps as in chrome then go back to chrome again and verify a change in ui. Is there anyway to do this using testcafe?

Comment: What is the second browsers job?

Comment: What is the behavior you want test? Why?

Comment: I want to login in chrome, once logged in some data will be added to my cookies and according to these I should be able to proceed to checkout. Now while chrome is opened, I want to open firefox or any other browser and login again. At this step if I went back to chrome I should fond that I am logged out. I want to test all of this in one single test. So was wondering if there is any way to toggle between browsers. I know testcafe provides some methods to toggle between windows but not different browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am glad I asked.

In order to test if a login in another browser triggers a logout in the current browser, there is no need to run a different browser.
You can send the according login command from your test code.

node.js builtin standard http library is sufficient for that task. The official documentation has a specific section on http requests: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request/

I personally prefer the fetch API as available in the browser. [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) provides this API in node.

so your test code could look a little like this:

```js
import 'node-fetch';
import { URLSearchParams } from 'url';

// we assume we get page state and interaction from this seperate module
import { loginAction, getIsLogged } from './page-actions';

fixture `login logut`
    .page `http://your.app/`;

test('User is logged out if logged in somewhere else', async t => {
    // perform the login actions to login as "username"
    await loginAction(t, 'yourUsername', 'yourPassword');
    
    await simulateLoginFromSomewhereElse('yourUsername', 'yourPassword');

    await t.expect(getIsLoggedIn(t)).eql(false);
});

async function simulateLoginFromSomewhereElse(username, password) {
    // build the (form) data to be sent to the server
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('username', 'yourUsername');
    params.append('password', 'yourPassword');

    await fetch(`http://your.app/login`, { method: 'POST', body: params });
}
```